# Deployment Strategy using Nginx and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I need help with setting up nginx and passenger on two separate machines. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've already finished setting up my nginx and now that I need to install passenger, Ive reached this road block and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: The passenger site is a good source of documentation. If you have specific issues, then I'd post new questions about them, instead of this one - it's far too broad.

http://modrails.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, but you have to let passenger-install-nginx-module build your Nginx installation.

Nginx doesn't have loadable modules like Apache. They must be compiled in.

passenger-install-nginx-module will walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Anyways, I got my setup working already. My 'appserver' which has nginx installed points to my nginx-passenger setup in my 'railsserver'. I used upstream to setup the nginx from the 'appserver' to point to the nginx in my 'railsserver'. I hope this is helpful to others.

Cheers!